HeadObject operation: Forbidden AWS Lambda
I have been following strictly to the tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html#with-s3-tutorial-create-policy
I am quite confident I have confirmed and run through every single steps highlighted in the tutorial. However, i still run into problem. The details of the error message is


{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "eb834711-562c-4d92-8607-f96d16aa56e6",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 23, in lambda_handler\n    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py\", line 192, in download_file\n    return transfer.download_file(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py\", line 406, in download_file\n    future.result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 103, in result\n    return self._coordinator.result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py\", line 266, in result\n    raise self._exception\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py\", line 269, in _main\n    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py\", line 354, in _submit\n    response = client.head_object(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 565, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 1021, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}



My policy for the lambda is


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tiral-bucket0973",
                "arn:aws:s3:::tiral-bucket0973/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket-152",
                "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket-152/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::tiral-bucket0973/example-folder-48523/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}



How can I resolve the issue. I know there are lots of discussions but nothing works.

The IAM policy includes both ListBucket and PutObject actions
for the example-folder-48523 path under tiral-bucket0973. However, ListBucket operates at the bucket level, while PutObject and GetObject operate at the object level (e.g., on specific file paths).
When you specify ListBucket with an object path like arn:aws:s3:::tiral-bucket0973/example-folder-48523/*, it will cause an error because ListBucket does not accept such a granularity. It should only refer to the bucket itself. you can try the below corrected policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tiral-bucket0973/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket-152/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tiral-bucket0973",
                "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket-152"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

